# How can I bypass the Oauth2 authentication with predefined tokens in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, token

In Spring Boot project, I want to bypass authentication for some "magic" tokens. For example, I get a request header parameter as **Authorization:Bearer abcdef-xyz**. If this is not a valid access token, I'll check my predefined tokens. If one of them is matched, I will create a dummy user for the Security Context, and allow the request to proceed.

Comment: Have you considered the security risk that this implies?

Comment: Yes, that dummy user will have a low level authorization. And that case will be used for trivial services.

Comment: Please, explain the security risks, then. These jokes have no use for anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to implement this.

- Override **readAccessToken** method on **InMemoryTokenStore**
- Check the token value according to your needs
- If the token fits your pattern, get related info from token and validate
- If it is validated then you can create a dummy authentication and call **storeAccessToken** method

  ```
  public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(String tokenValue) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(HRN_REGEX);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tokenValue);
  OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = super.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
  if (oAuth2AccessToken == null && matcher.find()) {
      String group = matcher.group();
      String companyStr = group.replace(LICENCE_TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
      Long companyId= Long.valueOf(companyStr);
      boolean isCompanyValid = mLoginUserService.validateCompanyIdForAnonymousLogin(companyId);
      if (isCompanyValid) {
          OAuth2Request storedReq = new OAuth2Request(generateDummyReqParameters(), CLIENT, null, true, generateScope(), generateResourceIds(), null, null, null);
          Authentication userAuth = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(companyStr, companyId, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(ROLE_COMPANY));
          OAuth2Authentication authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(storedReq, userAuth);
          storeAccessToken(new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(tokenValue), authentication);
          return new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(tokenValue);
      } else {
          throw new InvalidTokenException(COMPANY_IS_NOT_LICENCED);
      }
  }
  return oAuth2AccessToken;}
  ```
- Give a role to this authentication ("**ROLE_COMPANY**" in my case)
- In your ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter class override **configure(HttpSecurity http)** method and give this role to related endpoints

  ```
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/tools/validate/**").hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_COMPANY, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN)
          .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN);    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are aware of the security risk, see if the following solution works out.

> request header parameter as Authorization:Bearer abcdef-xyz

This will not be supported out-of-the-box by Spring-boot and if you want this solution, you will have to write custom implementation and that could be complex.

Rather, you can look at a solution where you create a Long expiring token with the low level authorization privileges that you want and ask your clients to send this token

To achieve this, set the accessTokenValiditySeconds to Zero or negative to make the token into non-expiring tokens

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to implement solution with present info on customer. On the other way I have to tell their token values to customers.